# How to remove the push notifications from the notifications in iOS/Swift

Tags: ios

How to remove the push notifications from the notifications in iOS/Swift., if it is not possible to remove notifications then please how to handle this kind of the situation.. Advance thanks for all.

Comment: Not possible, it's handled by system, not app

Comment: you can dismiss a notification if your app is running, but if it is in background, the OS handles your push notification. Unless you only develop for iOS 10.

Comment: @dirtydanee: What do you mean by "Unless you only develop for iOS 10" How is this possible in the background since iOS 10?